# Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[NSNull length]: unrecognized selector sent to instance

Tags: ios, swift

when I try to load a related field, I get this error: 
"*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[NSNull length]: unrecognized selector sent to instance"

I feel like it's caused by loading a collection of data that the compiler doesn't know what to do with.

Any help appreciated.

```
    func findPostsInGroup() {


    let whereClause = "GroupPostBelongsTo.objectId = 'B52F6BEA-79F8-A58B-FF15-AF840BCB2A00'"
    let dataQuery = BackendlessDataQuery()
    dataQuery.whereClause = whereClause
    print("hey")

    var error: Fault?
    let posts = self.backendless.persistenceService.find(Posts.ofClass(),
        dataQuery:dataQuery) as BackendlessCollection
     print("hey")

    if error == nil {
        for post in posts.data as! [Posts] {
            print("post class is \(post.PostText)")
            print("post class is \(post.objectId)")
            print(post.Author.name)


        }

    }

    else {
        print("Server reported an error: \(error)")
    }

}

import Foundation
```

Groups table class definition

```
    class Groups : NSObject{

    var groupName: String?
    var UsersInGroup = [BackendlessUser]()
    var ownerId: String?
    var objectId : String?
```

}

Comment: Did you check the `posts.data` value? Does it have something in it?

Comment: Which line is triggering that error? It's obvious you are trying to use `NSNull` instance (which is the result of a `null` somewhere) in place of a `String` or `NSString` instance. However, it's very difficult to see which line has that problem. It could be `post.Author.name`, for example.

Comment: Yes, it's post.Author.name.

Comment: posts.data has data in it.

Comment: Yup, the post.Author.name was empty. Making sure it wasn't by adding a value for it fixed that. Thank you.

Answer (score -1):

Yup, the post.Author.name was empty. Making sure it wasn't by adding a value for it fixed that. Thank you.